# Understanding compilation better

Tags: c, assembly, compilation

I'm asking this question to clarify that I understand certain things about compilation correctly or not. I'm going to describe a situation and assumptions that I hold about it. Please tell me if these assumptions are true, and if not, why.

Suppose I have a C program that compiles on one processor architecture, but two different operating systems, without any changes to the code. This program has parts of abstract logic, just calculating stuff and changing memory, and then some parts that interact with operating system.

1. I suppose that it means that these two binaries are completely identical in the places where abstract logic takes place, because it's just the same machine instructions, and only places where the program interacts with operating system, such as all kinds of IO and allocating memory, are different.
2. I also understand that these differences come only because the realization of, say, `<stdio.h>` is different for these operating systems.
3. And it's different because these operating systems have different standards for setting signals: what information to leave in each registers, which signal codes mean what, and so on, and these libraries need to be corrected to be compatible with this format on each OS.

Comment: I could've written the question in a different form, for example, "do programs compile differently only in IO parts?", but I just wanted the context and intention of my question to be clear.

Comment: If you want your question to be clear you may want to consider rewriting your title. Currently the title is very broad (not saying your question is).

Comment: How is that related to compilation? It would be the same for an interpreter actually. Heck, that whole is also true for an OS, or even simple drivers: they provide an abstraction for the underlying hardware. You have horizontal layering everywhere in software.

Comment: Different OSs may have different ABIs, which results in different calling conventions. They may also have differences in other implementation-defined details, like `sizeof(long)` on 64-bit OSs.

Comment: Your question and assumptions are at the wrong level. The exact same program can produce different code when compiled by two different point versions of the same compiler on the same host and operating system. Heck, the C standard doesn't even mandate that the same code is generated by the exact same compiler ... only the behavior is mandated. An important question is: why do you care about what you are asking about? It's hard to see how it tells you anything useful.

Comment: Also: "only places where the program interacts with operating system, such as all kinds of IO and allocating memory, are different" -- only if the differences are due to different code being compiled because of preprocessor switches. Otherwise, the code generated has nothing to do with what operating system will field the API calls. So the answer to your basic question is "or not"  -- you have a fundamental misunderstanding about compilation, because you don't seem to understand that system dependencies are in libraries, not code generation.

Comment: "I suppose that it means that these two binaries are completely identical" -- binaries are the result of *linking*, not just compilation. Link with different system libraries and of course the portion of the binary corresponding to that library will be different.

Comment: In summary: Your question is wrong ... what you need to understand better is how executables are constructed. And before anyone can answer, you need to answer some questions: Do you know what a library and an API is? Do you understand the difference between static and dynamic libraries? Do you understand what a linker is and how it works? The text of your question suggests that you don't.

Comment: @JimBalter I care because I'm curious. I never learned programming or math because it's "useful" for anything in the first place, just because it is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't specify whether you are using the same version of the same compiler, complete with the same optimization flags. You also don't specify whether both operating systems use the same object file format, or even the same calling conventions. If any of these don't match, neither will the binary.
2. If both operating systems follow the same standards, the header files may be pretty close to identical. (They don't have to be.) As others said, differences will be found in the libraries, and especially in the system call stubs. (Even if normal calling conventions match, conventions for invoking system calls need not match.)
3. What you are talking about here is what I've summarized as "calling conventions". That's only part of the difference. It's possible for two operating systems to have identical calling conventions on the same architecture - and the same compilers, etc - and still not have matching libraries.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Combined with the comments on the original answer, I have a pretty solid understanding of what should I dig into now.